# using group by in subquery in sql

Tags: sql, subquery

how to get around this error :

> Unable to use an aggregate or a subquery in an expression used in the
>   GROUP BY list of a GROUP BY clause.

here is my query :

```
select Id, name,dayA,monthA,yearA, 
    sum(x) as x,
    (select SUM(x) group by month) as total,
    from table_A
    group by Id,name,monthA,dAyA,yearA, SUM(x)
```

in other words : 
sample data :

```
id name dayA monthA yearA  x
===========================
1  name1  2    3     2016   4
2  name2  2    3     2016   3
3  name1  2    3     2016   2
```

Expected result :

```
id name dayA monthA yearA  x total
===================================
1  name1  2     3     2016  4  6
2  name2  2     3     2016  3  3 
3  name1  2     3     2016  2  6
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: the error comes from that your subquery has no `from`.  also it is no related to main query so after that correction, you will have same value on all output rows

Comment: Also your group by is extrange.  If it contains ID and that is a real ID, the rest of the fields there are not relevant, and each output record, comes from just one input record of the table, so SUMs are irrelevant too.

Comment: @GordonLinoff , please check now

Comment: @Magnolia  . . . Your sample data has nothing to do with the query.  The columns are not the same.

Comment: Also three records to show?  a bit few. Need to deduct too much

Comment: @LuisSiquot , you're right , please have a look :)

Comment: again, you expect somethig on diferent months, but show here just one value `3`.  Can you please do an effort asking.  deducted from `group by month) as total`

Comment: @LuisSiquot , thanks for your time , what i want is that : adding a column ' total ' where i can show sum of x , i put the value 3 because there is just one record with name = name2 , the value 6 is the sum of 4 + 2 , when names are the same ; hope that i'm more clear now :)

Comment: if 4 and 2 comes from two diferent months, do you still add them?

Comment: no, i count the total for each day of month , that's why there is a group by day, month and year

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you're query has more problem.

`(select SUM(x) group by month) as total`, is it from the same table, not likely since column month is not mention inyour group by.  When using sub query in a query, you must guaranteed that i will only return one record.

Based on your sample data and expected results...

```
     create table table_A(
id int,
name varchar(25),
dayA int,
monthA int,
yearA int,
x int
)

insert into table_A
values (1,'name1',2,3,2016,4),
        (2,'name2',2,3,2016,3),
        (2,'name1',2,3,2016,2)


select ta.id, ta.name, ta.dayA, ta.monthA, ta.yearA, ta.x, total.Total  from table_A as ta
left join 
(select name, sum(x) as Total from table_A group by name) total on ta.name = total.name
group by
ta.id, ta.name, ta.dayA, ta.monthA, ta.yearA, ta.x, total.name, total.Total
```

Comment: can you tell me how you get 6 3 6 on your total column?

Comment: of course , total is a column that stores the sum of x where names are equal, i get 6 by adding 4 to 2 ( names are the same : name1) , the value 3 because i have just one record with name equal name2 , and the second 6 is the same as the first one . Thank you

Comment: :).  you are doing group by month and you want count by name.  change (select top 1 SUM(x) from table_A where  montha = montha group by montha) as total to (select top 1 SUM(x) from table_A where  name= name group by name) as total

Comment: and what is the purpose of sum(x) as x,  it doesn't do anything since you're grouping it too.

Comment: yes it doesn't have a sense .. It's because i get an error that is said sum(x) must  exist in group by

Comment: You can if you want have a look on Kostya's answer , the only gap is that , the result isn't grouped by month ..

Comment: I give up your sample data and expected results has nothing to do with the month.   Your total suggest that is group by the month but when asked your explanation is that the total is what it is because it has the same name, not month.

Comment: i really thank you so mush , i'm based on your answer and i added month criteria just like this , and it is resolved : ' select ta.id, ta.name, ta.dayA, ta.monthA, ta.yearA, ta.x, total.Total  
from table_A as ta
left join 
(select name, monthA, sum(x) as Total from table_A group by name,monthA) total 
on ta.name = total.name
and ta.monthA = total.monthA
group by
ta.id, ta.name, ta.dayA, ta.monthA, ta.yearA, ta.x, total.name, total.Total '..... Thank you again for your time :)

Answer (score 0):

May be this is what you want:

```
select table_A.*, TotalSums.total
from table_A
left join (select name, monthA, dayA, yearA, sum(x) as total from table_A group by name, monthA, dayA, yearA) as TotalSums
    on table_A.name   = TotalSums.name
    and table_A.monthA = TotalSums.monthA
    and table_A.dayA = TotalSums.dayA
    and table_A.yearA = TotalSums.yearA
order by id
```

Comment: I am waiting your update, cos, my answer is not correct (I gess). Or I contemplate year, or I descart month. That is what sounds logical to me.

Comment: Unfortunately yes ... the columns name  in the second select are invalid

Comment: Yes Luis i tried with your last answer but it doesn't give me what i am expecting . I really thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

i think this is what you're looking for

```
select Id, main.name,dayA,main.monthA,main.yearA, 
    sum(x) as x,
    ,max(total.total) as total
    from table_A as main
    join (select SUM(x) total ,name ,monthA,yearA from table_A group by name,monthA,yearA) as total
    on main.name = total.name
     and main.monthA = total.monthA
     and main.yearA = total.yearA
    group by Id,main.name,monthA,dAyA,yearA
```

Comment: thank you so mush , but it doesn't group the value of total by monthA , all result records have the same value whatever the month is ....